# <iframe> isn't formatting properly on iphone safari

Tags: html, iframe, adobe, muse

I am using an iFrame to embed a delivery order form for a clients website and for some reason it isn't formatting properly for iPhone users. I have had multiple people tell me that the "view cart" button is at the very bottom of the page rather than sticking to the window like it does with android phones. The height of the iFrame is set to 450px for this specific reason with scrolling locked on. Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Website link for demo: http://minghouse.chatsumlin.com/delivery.html